# Passing one value along with a list to a map in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to map the function `math.pow` with the power of 2 to a list,
but the problem is that I should pass an iterable not just a single value.
So, I fixed it this way, by making a list of 2s with the same length as my list:

```
import math
lis = [1,2,3,4]
squred_lis = list(map(math.pow, lis, [2,2,2,2]))
print (squred_lis)
```

So, is there a way I can just pass a single value and have it passed every iteration as the second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat). It will repeat the value infinitely, and `map()` will iterate as many of them as necessary to match the length of `lis`.

```
import math
import itertools

lis = [1,2,3,4]
squared_lis = list(map(math.pow, lis, itertools.repeat(2)))
print(squared_lis)
```

which produces:

```
[1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

`squred_lis = list(map(math.pow, lis, [2 for _ in range(len(a))]))`

but.. how about this?

`squared_list = list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, a))`

Comment: In the first one it's still a list that is being passed.

the second is a good one, but actually I didn't mean the power fun specifically.. I'm trying to know if I can pass a single variables as parameters along with lists in a map?!